# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 ssh connexion reset (Permission Issue)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

First of all, sorry for the eye bleeds

At some point of various debugging, I kinda raged at permission issues and brought up the Exodia card

chmod -R 777 * .* /

And suddenly the DNS parameters of my instance started malfunctioning.

Every ping would give me Temporary failure in name resolution, even google.com

To solve the issue I decided to shut down and restart the instance.

On the event log, the instance seems to be able to start:

https://pastebin.com/ycC7XUNn

However, it's completely impossible to connect through SSH.
Neither through putty nor the built-in amazon online ssh client.

I checked the security group and VPC, no hiccups there.

I created another instance in the same subnet, same OS, and upon connecting I get an error

`Connection reset by 172.31.33.21 port 22`

I do think it's because I messed up the permission of key files in my system.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

I would like to either revert my instance in a working state, or at least recover some data and put it into a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

Created another Ubuntu 18.04 Instance
Turned off the faulty instance
Detached the volume from the faulty instance
Attached it to the new instance, and mounted it
Repaired the permissions on the mounted /etc/ssh keys
Unmounted and Remounted on the original instance
SSH Works!